# ng-touched not working - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Form fields not being added `ng-touched` class, instead remains `ng-pristine`

This is my form:

```
<form novalidate class="css-form">

            <div class="form-group clearfix">
                <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">State Code</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-maxlength="2" ng-model="ObjectNew.stateCode" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>

            <div class="form-group clearfix">
                <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">Zip</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ObjectNew.zip" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>

        </form>
```

When I see in inspect element, it does show only `ng-pristine` class on each field, even if i went through both fields and leaves null.
It shows `ng-invalid` too, which is fine.

Have to add the styles actually:

```
.css-form input.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
    background-color: #FA787E !important;
    }

  .css-form input.ng-valid.ng-touched {
    background-color: #78FA89 !important;
  }
```

Comment: Make sure you use Angular 1.3.x version.

Comment: Oops! currently using 1.2.26 - what I need to make sure after upgrading to 1.3x ? I mean do I lose something, some support?

Comment: Also, remmeber than `ng-touched` class will be added only when the element loses focus, not immediately after it is clicked.

Comment: Unlikely. But everything can be. Just upgrage and see if something breaks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The term `pristine` and `touched` are not similar. An input will remain `pristine` as long as it has not been modified. It is `untouched`, as long as it didn't loose focus - [Angular doc states](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) that `ng-touched` is applied when "the control has been blurred".

So it is possible for an input to be pristine and touched - just click it, and then click somewhere else without typing anything in.

It is also possible for it to be dirty and untouched - click it, type in some text, but **do not** click anywhere else.

To see that, and see working `ng-touched` in action, refer to this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amowc3jx/1/).

To make sure it works, use Angular 1.3 as pointed out by @dfsq. Also, use `angular-touch` which matches your Angular version. The JSFiddle above works correctly.